# How do I loop an ultimate thread group in JMeter?

Tags: loops, jmeter, jmx, jmeter-plugins, threadgroup

I have a scenario of a 3 hour test case (see comment in the picture) in JMeter and I need it to be repeated for 20 times, until it reaches 60 hours. It goes as the picture shows.
So I used an ultimate thread group, I configured the values for the times and counts for the 3 hour scenario.

How do I repeat it for 20 hours?
[image]

I tried to use a different thread groups or a loop controller but didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The easiest solution is just running your test 20 times [in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and appending the results into the same .jtl results file.
2. Your workload model can be expressed via [`threads_schedule` special property](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/#Special-Property-Processing)

   For example if you put the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   threads_schedule=spawn(50,0s,0s,3600s,200s) spawn(450,3600s,1800s,0s,0s) spawn(450,5400s,0s,3600s,0s) spawn(450,9000s,0s,0s,1800s) spawn(50,9000s,1800s,0s,0s)
   ```

   and add an empty [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/#Ultimate-Thread-Group) to your test plan you will see your workload model despite the fact you didn't provide any numbers in the Ultimate Thread Group

   So if you replicate the above `threads_schedule` property 20 times adjusting "Initial delay" accordingly you will be able to achieve your desired workload model pattern.

   More information on JMeter Properties and ways of setting and overriding them: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: this solution is right, but I have many different ultimate thread groups that don't need to be on repeat (they have different values) and they are also affected by the user properties file. Is there any way to repeat/affect only one of them using your second solution?

Comment: In that case you can consider switching to [Open Model Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-model-thread-group) which also supports defining the workload model via pseudo-code